# Logo with custom sound and navigation to welcome page flutter

Tags: flutter

Mp3 file is working fine. But navigation to next page is not working.  and also in audiocache no stop method. The page should load the logo with music and navigate to the next page.

Navigation is working but how to move to the next page.
initstate is not working.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'welcomepage.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(

      home:Home(),


    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  AudioCache audioCache = AudioCache();
   AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    Timer(Duration(seconds:3), ()=> Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> Welcome())));
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    AudioCache audioCache = AudioCache();
    audioCache.load('mus.mp3');
    audioCache.play('mus.mp3');



    return Scaffold(

      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Image.asset('assets/images/logo.jpeg'),




        ],

      ),

    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try :

In `inintState`

```
 void initState(){
        super.initState();
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
            await audioCache.load('mus.mp3'); // I don't sure it need await or not in load file
            player = await audioCache.play('mus.mp3'); 
            Timer(Duration(seconds:3), (){
                player?.stop(); 
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: 
                (context)=> Welcome()));});
        }
    }
```

In `build`

```
//AudioCache audioCache = AudioCache();
//audioCache.load('mus.mp3');
//audioCache.play('mus.mp3');
```